# Running compiled bytecode from JRuby in Java service

Tags: java, classloader, jruby, bytecode, precompile

I am working on building a **Java service** which will take as input below:

1. **Pre-compiled java function as bytecodes** and
2. Relevant parameters

   Now it's also possible that parameters is already available in the service or it might fetch them from some other service so currently we are keeping it optional.

**The main question is my service needs to execute that bytecode function and return the result or just execute the task depending on whether that function returns anything or not.**
Bytecode come from a legacy application developed on JRuby. As the legacy code is complex(and working!) and we don't want to take the pain of re-writing same thing again. Ultimately even if we re-write(just syntax change) end result is going to be just bytecode. So if we aleady have bytecode this approach makes sense.

I haven't done anything similar before. But may be loading bytecode via classloader help which I will try. Hoping to gain from experienced users here.

Comment: just to clarify, your JRuby legay app produces byte-code that you want to consume as an input? sounds a bit far fetched esp. since JRuby is primarily a Ruby interpreter with a JIT ... so my naive guess was that you receive the JIT-ed pieces (doesn't make much sense)?